# Get response from Curl but not Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, cookies

I tried to run the Curl command in the terminal. I can get the response in JSON. But when I convert the Curl to Python Code and run the python script, the script returned an html page. It looks like it is a captcha page.

Why they can detect the difference? Any way I can bypass that?

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://www.99.co/api/v2/web/search/listings?query_type=city&property_segments=residential&listing_type=sale&rental_type=unit&page_size=1&page_num=100&zoom=11&show_future_mrts=true&show_cluster_preview=true&show_internal_linking=true' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0' \
--header 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
--header 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
--header 'if-none-match: W/"5cb28158470b6eb63b0db1f5dd2adda7d10c328c"' \
--header 'cookie: _xsrf=2|6be6c7ee|de091e966dba87e0b2c8637a63127715|1616479899' \
--header 'cookie: lotameid=undefined' \
--header 'cookie: started_since=1616480838' \
--header 'cookie: country=SG' \
--header 'cookie: nid=2de067d4-fed8-4c35-b7db-14f479997f8a' \
--header 'cookie: g_state={"i_p":1627551635034,"i_l":1}' \
--header 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
--header 'te: trailers' \
--header 'sec-gpc: 1'
```

```
import requests

url = "https://www.99.co/api/v2/web/search/listings?query_type=city&property_segments=residential&listing_type=sale&rental_type=unit&page_size=1&page_num=100&zoom=11&show_future_mrts=true&show_cluster_preview=true&show_internal_linking=true"

payload={}
headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"5cb28158470b6eb63b0db1f5dd2adda7d10c328c"',
  'cookie': '_xsrf=2|6be6c7ee|de091e966dba87e0b2c8637a63127715|1616479899',
  'cookie': 'lotameid=undefined',
  'cookie': 'started_since=1616480838',
  'cookie': 'country=SG',
  'cookie': 'nid=2de067d4-fed8-4c35-b7db-14f479997f8a',
  'cookie': 'g_state={"i_p":1627551635034,"i_l":1}',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'te': 'trailers',
  'sec-gpc': '1'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: This looks like an oddity on CloudFlare. I tried your URL with 2 different browsers and it always seems to work. However, when I tried with Postman it worked initially then stopped after subsequent attempts. In the HTML response you will see "We are checking your browser... www.99.co". Still working to try to understand how you can (possibly) overcome this

Comment: I've now tried curl (a copy'n'paste of your code) and it is now also failing with 403. You might want to read this:- https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/849

Comment: @AndyKnight Curl still works on my end.